# Concat linq to objects Or queries with LINQKIT during runtime

Tags: c#, linq, linqkit

I have a list of multiple values 3,5,10.

Now I want to create a linq `.where` filter during runtime with the Or operator.

How can I do this using LINQKit? Or with plain linq but I dont think its possible.

E.g. this would be a hardcoded version:

```
var filter = mydata.Where(v => v.state == "3" || v.state == "5" || v.state == "10");
```

This would filter mydata array dynamically.

But I do not want it to be hardcoded!

Comment: Try `Where(v => list.Contains(v.state))`.

Comment: hell... did I think complicated... Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the `Contains` method like this:

```
var filter = mydata.Where(v => list.Contains(v.state));
```